# AJAX loaded content to be crawable by google

Tags: javascript, jsonp, google-crawlers

Here is my case: I use some external source to load html data to my page, after that I put content of this html to div. So, as soon as page loaded and ajax call finished, I see the results.

It works, Ok.. but now I came up, that this dynamically loaded content is not crawable by Google bot.. and this is something that I don't like :)

Are there any ways to say to google bot, that page  page, actually contains a content of  page?

For example, if I loaded a page from http://external.com/test.htm, and loaded it to div, can I use something like

```
<div id="dynamic"></div>
<a href="http://external.com/test.htm"></a>
```

?

I hope you understand my question, if not, please make your comments!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in checking out the following document directly from Google, for a few concrete tips:

- [Google Code: Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thansk Daniel, sure I checked the doc.. but this is not something what I need.. I thought there are some more lightweight approach for my simple case